# To connect mongodb Atlas with the python?

Tags: python, mongodb

I want to connect the python with the mongodb Atlas using .py file. I tried to insert data into the  collection using following code but got error as follows??

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("******************************")//Here *********is connection string

for db in client.list_database_names():
    if db in ['admin','local']:
        pass
    else:
        for collection in client[db].list_collection_names():
            print(collection)
            collection.insert_one(data)

print("successfully inserted")
```

**but got error on the line collection.insert_one as follows?**

*Attribute:'str' object has no attribute 'insert_one'*

Comment: client[db][collection].insert_one...

Comment: Helllo, NobbyNobbs this method work . is there be any other method to do it also?